# Event Page, Code at the top...?

Tags: civievent

I have no idea at what time it occurred, but a user mailed me because of an error at our event page.

At the top of the list we see some code, as below:

[image: Screenshot]

System: Joomla! 3.10.1 Stable [ Daraja ] 22-August-2021; PHP 7.4.16; CiviCRM 5.36.1

At the moment I have no Idea where to start. Does anybody have a suggestion where to start? Thank you!

Comment: It may help others if you could add your CiviCRM Version as well as the CMS & version you are using.

Comment: Sorry!
Joomla! 3.10.1 Stable [ Daraja ] 22-August-2021
PHP 7.4.16
CiviCRM 5.36.1

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, **AdminTools by Akeeba** is blocking a request.

Please try to deactivate

PHP stream wrappers block (PHPShield)
Direct File Inclusion shield (DFIShield)
PHP session data poisoning protection (SessionShield)

from the WAF/Request Filtering section or temporarily deactivate AdminTools.

[image]

Regards,

Comment: Thank you for the hint Guitarman.

I have disabled all the Filters in "Request Filtering" and in a second step disabled the admin tools WAF by unpublishing the System - Admin Tools plugin. That leaves the enhanced .htaccess file.

However, there is no change at the Event-Page, still the code at the top. As I had experienced odd (cache) behaviour in Firefox, I checked with a chromium browser, but same behaviour.